# Impact of moving the ldf and mdf files temporarily for few hours

Tags: sql-server, backup, system-databases, master-system-database

I want to copy my database files(ldf and mdf) into a separate box for few hours as there is a disk space issue in my current sql server box.
Currently i have mdf in one drive(:D) and ldf in another drive(:E).
I have to move both mdf and ldf into same drive,say :D.
I understand that it is recommended to have separate disk drives for LDF and MDF ,but this is a DEV box and to avoid purchase/delay client wants to go with this option.

I have two plans:

1. Take backups of all systems databases and user databases and save it
   in a separate box.
2. Move MDF and LDF to a separate box for few hours

So after the partitioning/merging of disk drives are completed i can either:

1. Restore the backups.
2. Move the MDF and LDF to the merged drive.

For user database ,i understand that the below steps will be sufficient:

- Bring the database offline
- Move the file(s) to the new location manually.
- Update the system catalog settings:

  `ALTER DATABASE DBNAME
          MODIFY FILE (
              NAME = 'DBNAME',
              FILENAME = 'D:\SQL_Data\DBNAME.mdf'
          )
          GO`

  `ALTER DATABASE DBNAME
      MODIFY FILE (
          NAME = 'DBNAME_log',
          FILENAME = 'D:\SQLLog\DBNAME_log.ldf'
      )`
- Bring the database online

Can someone explain the dangers of second step or direct me how to do second step for **system databases**.?

Comment: Moving system databases other then master is similar to moving user database. If you need to move master database. This MS link guide you step-by-step to move master and other system databases. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You should don't have any issues I have done this many times before with no big issues.

One thing to consider is that if you have binaries in  E drive, you may have some issues, otherwise should be ok to go.

From what I remember in the past you should check OS privileges, once  I had issues with the SQL Server account access to the drives.

Another tip: If you plan to go with the move of the datafiles, you may want to try to shrink the tlog files before put offline, this way you will save some MB/GB and copy time will be faster.

Comment: If the dev box is a newer version of SQL Server that would be a problem...